# Ascending and descending order in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just starting to learn Python and this is my problem:

I am taking input *a* and *b* and if a < b then then output is a to b in ascending order. If a > b then the output is in descending order. When I put in a < b it works but it gives me nothing when a >b. This is the code:

```
a = int(input('input a number for a: '))
b = int(input('input a number for b: '))

numbers = list(range(a, b + 1))

if a < b:
    print(numbers)

else:
    numbers.sort(reverse=True)
    print(numbers)
```

This is the output when a > b:

```
input a number for a: 10
input a number for b: 1
[]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: That's what it's supposed, documented, and expected to do.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range. The last example corresponds to your situation.

Comment: The range function can have up to 2 arguments: start, stop and step. If you don't specify step it will be set to 1 by default. If you want to get from a higher number to a lower one your step has to be negative or the result will be an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
a = int(input('input a number for a: '))
b = int(input('input a number for b: '))

print(list(range(a, b + (b >= a) - (a > b), 1 - 2 * (a > b))))
```

Answer (score 0):

When a is 10 and b is 2 your code is doing:

```
>>> numbers = list(range(10, 2))
>>> numbers
[]
```

Maybe you want to do:

```
numbers = list(range(min(a, b), max(a, b) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the last value [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) prints is the biggest value for `start + step * i` that is less than `end`. If `end` is less than `start` and the `step` is positive, there is no number which satisfies that condition:

`10 + i * 1` will never be smaller than 1 (where `i` is a positive integer)

Instead, do this before you range:

```
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
```

which will ensure a is always the smaller number moving forward, by swapping their values if that is not the case.

If you want to preserve the ascending/descending order:

```
if a > b:
    a, b = b, a
    rev = True
```

Then, after building the list

```
if rev:
    numbers.reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what you want to do is this....

```
a = int(input('input a number for a: '))
b = int(input('input a number for b: '))

list = []

if a > b:
    while a > b: 
        list.append(a)
        a -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `numbers` to the following:

```
numbers = list(range(a, b + 1)) if a < b else list(range(b, a + 1))
```

and your code will work just fine. You can also shorten your code by doing it like this:

```
a = int(input('input a number for a: '))
b = int(input('input a number for b: '))
numbers = list(range(a, b+1)) if a < b else list(range(b, a+1))
print numbers if a < b else sorted(numbers, reverse=True)
```